# Turtles has to die after few ticks after collision

Tags: netlogo

Turtles has to die after few ticks after collision?

problem in TICK position and some issue with Turtles-own and its implementation?

Turtles has to die after few ticks after collision

```
  turtles-own [ functioning ]  
globals [ non-functioning-ticks    ]
    to setup

  clear-all
  ;ask turtles [set functioning True]
 create-bikes 1 [
    set functioning true
   ]]
  create-cycles 1 [set functioning true]
end
to go
 ifelse functioning = true
  [        show functioning
    ask turtles [ move ]]
  [        show functioning
    ask turtles [after-collision]
[
  if not any? turtles [ stop ]
  tick
end
to move
 ask bikes [set color blue
 fd 1 ]
ask cycles [set color blue
    fd 1]
ask turtles with radius 1
      set functioning False
      set color red    ]]]
end   
to after-collision    
  ifelse non-functioning-ticks >= 3
  [ die ]
  [        set non-functioning-ticks non-functioning-ticks + 1  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have non-functioning-ticks as a global variable. If you think about it, each turtle needs its own copy as some will be alive and some will collide. This is a problem throughout your code. Anything that is potentially different for some turtles must be defined by a `turtles-own` statement instead of a `globals` statement. You then need to change the value of that variable with a `set` (as for globals) but you have to tell NetLogo which turtles to change the value for. So you will have something like:

```
ask turtles with [<some condition>]
[ set <variable> <value>
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new state (perhaps called `collided` or `collision-time`) that can be referenced in `after-collision` that's where you're going to increase the ticks, when they're `>= 3` then you kill it.